# Achieved Bandwidth of CUDA Kernel calculation

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, bandwidth, memory-access

I'm trying to calculate the effective bandwidth of this kernel:

```cpp
__global__ void compute_flags(int nquarts, int4 *d_flag, int4 * dat_arr, int * arr, int array_size){
    int gi = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (gi < nquarts) {
        int4 res = {0, 0, 0, 0};
        int4 dat = dat_arr[gi];

        for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
            int p = arr[i];
            res.x = res.x | (p == dat.x);
            res.y = res.y | (p == dat.y);
            res.z = res.z | (p == dat.z);
            res.w = res.w | (p == dat.w);
        }
        d_flag[gi] = res;
    }
}
```

But I am getting unrealistic numbers: 1.5TB/s for a theoretical bandwidth of 448 GB/s.

Currently I am calculating the number of accesses as:

```cpp
2 * n_kernel_calls * sizeof(int4) + n_kernel_calls * array_size * sizeof(int)
```

The first term takes into account the access done to read `dat` and to write `d_flag`, the second term considers the reads from the second array inside the for loop.

The `res` and `dat` variable's accesses are not considered because it is loaded into registers.

The complete code I am using is the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define arr_size 1000000

int round_div_up (int a, int b){
    return (a + b - 1)/b;
}

void cuda_err_check (cudaError_t err, const char *file, int line)
{
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "CUDA error: %s (%s:%d)\n", cudaGetErrorString (err), file, line);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

__global__ void compute_flags(int nquarts, int4 *d_flag, int4 * dat_arr, int * arr, int array_size){
    int gi = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (gi < nquarts) {
        int4 res = {0, 0, 0, 0};
        int4 dat = dat_arr[gi];

        for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
            int p = arr[i];
            res.x = res.x | (p == dat.x);
            res.y = res.y | (p == dat.y);
            res.z = res.z | (p == dat.z);
            res.w = res.w | (p == dat.w);
        }
        d_flag[gi] = res;
    }
}

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int V1 [arr_size] = {};
    int V2 [arr_size] = {};

    // fill with random numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++){
        V1[i] = rand() % 100;
        V2[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    
    int4 *d_flag;
    int * d_V1;
    int * d_V2;
    cudaError_t err;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;

    err = cudaEventCreate(&start); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    err = cudaEventCreate(&stop); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);

    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_flag, arr_size * sizeof(int)); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_V1, arr_size * sizeof(int)); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_V2, arr_size * sizeof(int)); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);

    err = cudaMemcpy(d_V1, V1, arr_size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    err = cudaMemcpy(d_V2, V2, arr_size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);

    uint64_t nquarts = round_div_up(arr_size, 4);
    uint64_t lws = 256;
    uint64_t gws = round_div_up(nquarts, lws);

    err = cudaEventRecord(start); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);

    compute_flags<<<gws, lws>>>(nquarts, d_flag, (int4*)d_V1, d_V2, arr_size);

    err = cudaEventRecord(stop); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    err = cudaEventSynchronize(stop); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);

    err = cudaGetLastError(); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    err = cudaDeviceSynchronize(); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);

    uint64_t byte_accesses = 2 * nquarts * sizeof(int4) + nquarts * arr_size * sizeof(int);
    float time;

    err = cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop); cuda_err_check(err, __FILE__, __LINE__);

    cout << "Time: " << time << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "Bandwidth: " << byte_accesses / time / 1e6 << " GB/s" << endl;

}
```

Is someone able to point me to the correct calculation and/or where my logic fails?

Comment: By `n_kernel_calls` you mean the number of active threads, i.e. `nquarts`?

Comment: As the GPU has caches and `arr[i]` can be broadcast among the lanes of a warp, you wont see much of the second term. I recommend taking a look at the kernel with Nsight Compute. It has a [nice graphical representation](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/ProfilingGuide/index.html#memory-chart) of the different bandwidths and can show you cache hit rates as well.